# How to call the same method in several Clojure namespaces?

Tags: clojure

I have a seq of namespace symbols:

```
(def namespace-symbols (namespace-1 namespace-2 namespace-3))
```

and I want to call the *exact same method* (say, `run`) over each one.

```
(map #{%/run} namespace-symbols)
```

won't work.

I also tried

```
(defmacro namespace-run
  [namespace]
  `(~(identity namespace)/run))
```

which also doesn't work. Is there any way to do this?

### Update:

I finally came up with a macro like this:

```
(defmacro namespace-run
  [namespace]
  `(~(symbol (str namespace "/run"))))

(macroexpand-1 '(namespace-run foobar))
;=> (foobar/run)
```

Surely there is a better way to do this?

Comment: look at @Kyle solution, you definitely don't need a macro for this task

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [clojure.core/ns-resolve](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/ns-resolve)

```
(doseq [ns namespace-symbols]
  ((ns-resolve ns 'run))) ;; resolve and execute fn
```

You can treat it just like a `fn`

```
(let [p (ns-resolve *ns* 'println)]
  (p "Hello")
  (p "World"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use someting like `symbol`

```
clojure.core/symbol
([name] [ns name])
  Returns a Symbol with the given namespace and name.
```